# GMPy - type checking in python C-api

Tags: python-c-api

I am trying to understand how to type check using python C-api.

To achieve this, I am studing the source code of [GMPy](https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy), where they check if the argument
to a function is an integer using the macro `IS_INTEGER(x)`, which itself is defined
based on a function `PyInt_Check`.

However, I tried `grep "PyInt_Check" -r` and I cannot
find the definition of `PyInt_Check` in the source code.

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the definition of `PyInt_Check` be on the GMPy folder?

Comment: Might it be in a header that GMPy uses instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyInt_Check` is part of the python c-api, and you'll find it declared in your copy of python.h. You can read the details online https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_Check